# How can I move an element to the top corner without using position: fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, position

```css
.main-section {
  padding-top: 79px;
  padding-left: 500px;
  width: 903px;
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.background {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wholeArea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.title {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #132c54;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.description {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #2569c8;
  line-height: 29px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.inputText {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #132c54;
  background-color: white;
}

.inputField {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #132c54;
  border-color: #132c54;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  outline-color: #132c54;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.noDecoration {
  /* No Text Decoration */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #132c54;
}

.selectInput {
  width: 413px;
  color: #132c54;
  outline-color: #132c54;
  outline-width: 0px;
  border-color: #132c54;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.textInput {
  width: 400px;
  display: inline;
  color: #132c54;
  outline-color: #132c54;
  outline-width: 0px;
  border-color: #132c54;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.selectOption {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #132c54;
}

.buttonStyle {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #132c54;
  background-color: white;
  outline-color: #132c54;
  outline-width: 0px;
  border-color: #132c54;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.buttonToggleStyle {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #132c54;
  background-color: white;
  outline-color: #132c54;
  outline-width: 0px;
  border-color: #132c54;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.radioStyle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.leftColumnBox {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 100px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.leftColumnBox2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 321px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.rightColumnBox {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 100px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.rightColumnBox2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 321px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.leftColumn {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 81px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.rightColumn {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 81px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 400px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.advertImage {
  border: 10px white solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

.resultsSection {
  display: none;
}

.radioArea {
  height: 45px;
  width: 700px;
  display: block;
}

.inputArea {
  height: 50px;
  width: 700px;
  display: block;
}

.labelText {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.resultsText {
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.resultsHeaderText {
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hideInput {
  display: block;
}

.mainBorder {
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: white;
}

.titleBorder {
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  background-color: white;
}

.descBorder {
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  background-color: white;
}

.tabContent {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.tabSwitch {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

I am trying to move a div into the top corner of a page to act as a background. When I use position: fixed;, the other elements of the page are shifted around but when I use position: relative, the are in the correct position. I want to make the div sticky when I scroll so it always stays in the same position in the background.

How can I do this?

```
.background {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
right: 0px; }
```

```
<span id="background" class="background"></span>
```

Comment: Position `fixed` or `sticky` are the correct options. *the other elements of the page are shifted around* - that means you have other CSS problems. Can you include minimal example?

Comment: To use `.background` you need to add `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to the span.

Comment: Is there any problems with the css code?

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.background {
 position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  float:right;
  
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<span id="background" class="background">akshay</span>
<p>consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis  s interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed orn, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).